# Use of Union with reference

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, visual-studio-2015, unions

At work I've been using linux and the GCC compiler for C++11 and C++14. In some of the code at work, I've used a union to store both a reference and a pointer, as so: (Simplified to just the important parts)

```
struct MyStruct
{
    //Stuff
    union { double& x; double* x_ptr; };
    MyStruct(double& value) : x(value) {}
    //More stuff
};
```

I believe this code is clear, readable, unambiguous, and provides a convenient way to store references which can be shifted to something else. It provides easily understandable syntactic sugar without costing performance while improving readability. When I attempted to use code like this in visual studio 15, however, the code failed to compile due to "an illegal union member of type double&".

1. Is this code illegal under the standard, or just under Visual Studio 2015?
2. Can I MAKE it compile in Visual Studio 2015, or submit a bug report/change request/something?
3. Is use of a union in that way bad practice?

Note: At my work, pretty much all code is written for Linux and compiled with GCC, and for my specific project, C++11 is guaranteed and GCC is the only compiler that's going to be used.

**Edit:** Please don't tell me that putting a reference inside a union "has no meaning". When a reference is stored inside a struct, it takes up the same amount of space as a pointer. In addition, the following compiles with clang:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    //This will compile
    union 
    { 
        struct { double& x; }; 
        double* x_ptr; 
    };
    //This won't compile; WHY?
    /*union 
    { 
        double& x;
        double* x_ptr; 
    };*/
    MyStruct(double& val) : x(val){}
    void Repoint(double& new_value) 
    { 
        x_ptr = &new_value; 
    }
};
```

Why does it compile when the reference is wrapped in an anonymous struct, but not when it's just in the union?

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/918a7b3d1652e112)</kbd>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to @Brian:
You can make it compile by using e.g. `std::reference_wrapper` instead of a plain reference:

```
#include <functional>

struct MyStruct
{
    //Stuff
    union { std::reference_wrapper<double> x; double* x_ptr; };
    MyStruct(double& value) : x(value) {}
    //More stuff
};

int main()
{
    double value = 123;
    MyStruct myStruct(value);
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/854677760453e0de)</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

It is illegal for a union to contain a reference member. This is presumably because references are not objects and it's unspecified whether or not they occupy storage---so it makes little sense for a reference to share its storage with other variables.

> A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual (10.3) functions.
>   A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class. If a union contains a non-
>   static data member of reference type the program is ill-formed.

([class.union]/2)

Comment: When a struct contains a reference, the reference is stored as a pointer. There's no ambiguity.

Comment: @JorgePerez It might be. It might also be optimized out in some instances. It is *not specified* by the standard.