# How to override generic function for aguments `const T&` and `T&&` where T could be a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to implement something like Rust's `Result<T,E>` type in C++, which is a union that holds either `T` or `E` value.

Some of its constructors are:

```
template <typename T, typename E>
Result<T,E>::Result(const T& value) : isOk(true), value(value) {}

template <typename T, typename E>
Result<T,E>::Result(T&& value) :  isOk(true), value(std::move(value)) {}
```

It works as I expect for `T` and `E` being non-reference types or pointers, but fails to compile if any of the underlying types is a reference. For example:

```
MyType my_object;
Result<MyType&, AnyOtherType> result(my_object);
```

produces the following error:

```
./result.h:46:5: error: multiple overloads of 'Result' instantiate to the same signature 'void (MyType &)'
    Result(T&& value);
    ^
main.cpp:39:23: note: in instantiation of template class 'Result<MyType &, int>' requested here
  Result<MyType&,int> result(object);
                      ^
./result.h:37:5: note: previous declaration is here
    Result(const T& value);
    ^
```

I understand that this is because of the reference collapsing rules (& + && = &): if `T` is `MyType&`, then `T&` and `T&&` are both `MyType&`, hence those two constructors have the same signature here.

But is there any nice way to overcome this, and allow `T` to be a reference, while still having both `const T&` and `T&&` constructors?

Comment: Do you want `Result` to store a reference, or do you want it to have it's own object?

Comment: What data do you want `Result<MyType&, AnyOtherType>` to store, and what constuctors do you want it to have?

Comment: @NathanOliver, @n.m., if `T` is a reference (like `MyType&`), then I want it to store the reference, otherwise, it should create it's own the object, either by moving it or copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a templated constructor with a forwarding reference to cover both cases:

```
template<typename T>
struct Result {
    template<typename... S>
    Result(S&&... s) : t(std::forward<S>(s)...) {}

    T t;
};

int i;
Result<int&> r1(i);
Result<int> r2(i);
```

Related papers on `std::expected<R, E>` proposal:

- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4109.pdf
- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0323r7.html

Comment: And so SFINAE to cover `T` vs `E`.

Comment: @Jarod42, shouldn't it be a tag that distinguishes between constructors? What if `T` and `E` are the same type?

Comment: Make it `template<typename ... S>
    Result(S&& ... s)` while you're at it.

Comment: From class purpose T != E, as T is the return type, and E is the error type.

Comment: Thanks! A lot of things for me to learn and understand here. What is this `...` syntax with template arguments?

This answers the question, but unfortunately I'm still unable to compile it, since my members are defined as: `union { T value; E error }`, and when I make `T` a reference, I get this: `error: union member 'value' has reference type 'MyType &'`. Nevertheless, it is another issue. Thank you!

Comment: @AndriiZymohliad, it's an argument pack, so that you can write `Result<T>(a, b, c, ...)` with an arbitrary number of arguments and pass all of them to the constructor of `T`: `t(a, b, c, ...)`. To put a reference into a union, you can use `std::reference_wrapper`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691282/use-of-union-with-reference

Comment: @Evg, thanks. So as I understand, to make it generic over references and non-references, I should somehow detect if `T` is a reference, and then only if it is create `std::reference_wrapper` around it?

Comment: @Jarod42, conceptually `T` might be the same as `E` (e.g. success value is some string, and error is the error message, so both would be strings). So to avoid any collisions here I made constructors only for success objects, and error objects are created with a static function Result::Error().

Comment: @AndriiZymohliad, one possible solution is to make it always hold a non-reference, and then if someone wants to put a reference into `Result`, he uses `std::reference_wrapper` himself.

Comment: @AndriiZymohliad, also take a look at this paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4109.pdf